# tabBarIcon Not Rendering Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid

Tags: react-native, expo-router

I am getting the above error when trying to render `tabBarIcon` in my `_layout.js` file for my Tabs.

Code:

```
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons/Feather";

const TabsLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Home"
        options={{
          title: "Home",
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            <Feather name="home" color={color} size={size} />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Favourite"
        options={{
          title: "Favourites",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            <Feather name="heart" color={color} size={size} />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Message"
        options={{
          title: "Messages",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            <Feather name="message-square" color={color} size={size} />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Account"
        options={{
          title: "Account",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            <Feather name="user" color={color} size={size} />;
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default TabsLayout;
```

Full Error:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

### EDIT:

Have changed my import to:

```
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons/Feather";
```

Have changed my tabBarIcon function to:

```
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Feather name="heart" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
```

### Latest Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forget to return something in your tabBarIcon props. If you use curly brackets, you need to use `return()` to tell components what you output. Or simply just use brackets`()`.

Replace

```
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {<Feather name="heart" color={color} size={size} />;},
```

by

```
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (<Feather name="heart" color={color} size={size} />),
```

---

**Edit**

Mark sure your import format is correct for default import or named import. Please edit your Feather icon import.

```
//Default import
import Feather from "@expo/vector-icons/Feather";
```

or

```
//Named import
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
```

After you editted the import, there maybe cache issue for the simulator, see here to clear cache. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8368.

Comment: getting the error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 19): It mentions "SOME LONG URL".ttf' doesn't exist. Please make sure directory exists before calling downloadAsync

with this suggestion, must be something else.

Comment: It means compiler cannot find the font file (.ttf) in your expo project. You may try import `Feather` icons by `import Feather from "@expo/vector-icons/Feather";`.

Comment: I've added /Feather to my import, however, now it's Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) But i'm passing the string as 'name="Heart"'

Comment: I cannot figure out any errors from the error message. Would you please update your question with latest code and error, or create an expo snack to debug?

Comment: I've updated the question to the latest error which is; Check the render method of 'TabBarIcon'

Comment: Never used expo snack before so I've added one here: https://snack.expo.dev/DAu5Hv8ho

Comment: @DavidHenry I have editted the answer. I see your snack still import Feather incorrectly. Hope this solve the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253306/discussion-between-david-henry-and-kiuq).